# how to not use emails for users in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a membership database application for my club.  I am using Laravel 5 to build this solution.

I have the standard auth setup and a profile table that contains most of the members data.  All members are profiled, but not necessarily active users.

What I want to do is replace registration with activation.  a user and profile is created, then disabled by default unless granted by an administrator for a member to log in.  This way it's simpler then to attempt to attach a profile to a new user.

When granted, the user will activate their user access by providing a couple of values from their profile data to validate who they are.  From there, they change password and can see their profile.

My question is how do I replace registration with activation in this instance?  Thank you.

Comment: While this is not an "answer" ( this is comment section after all )  I would say you should consider setting an expiration time on those accounts and running a timed Cron job to remove them, no sense cluttering up your DB with hundreds of "dead" records.

Comment: Typically you would want to send an email that has some kind of hashed "code" and when used the page it points to will flip the account on.  In laravel I dont know, never used it.  I use only PHP

Answer (score 0):

Various ways you can achieve this activity

1. You can maintain an attribute in users table, whether he is activated or not, so even if he is logged in while browsing the site, if the user is not activated he will be shown limited content and a notice of awaiting activation
2. If you don't wish to show me anything if not activated, then you can override authenticated function in LoginController and force logout with error message as awaiting activation

*example*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
...

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if (!$user->activated) {
            \Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Awaiting activation');
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about Authentication - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users

If you want to go with first way, to protect it furthermore you can create a middleware and have it called for every route to make sure user don't temper with URL to get unwanted access.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ActivatedUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!$user->activated) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Awaiting activation');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Read more about Middlewares - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Comment: This is beautiful information.,  This takes me a great distance towards my goal.  where in y our code do I inject the "activation" page?  I want the user to have to insert values into a form to prove who they are, so they're user account to activate?

Comment: Didn't understand what information you are looking that user will have to enter, if admin is approving the account, on Admin Dashboard, he can see the un-activated accounts easily by _where_ clause on your activated field and have a button to activate that just turns `0` to `1`